# Excel VBA SUMIFS on multiple range objects with a condition referencia a pivot table

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, pivot-table, sumifs

I'm trying to build a macro to create a table based on SUMIfs formula with 2 criteria.
The first criteria Range takes values from a table without table format and the number of rows changes daily, so I use LastRow examples from the internet. and the criteria for this case is "C" for purchasing in Spanish

the second criteria Range is another column from the same table without table formatting and criteria 2 comes from the value of a row within a pivot table

```
'Generar Formulas de a Partir de L (C= Montos de Compra)
    Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(3).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "C"
    Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select

'Se aplica la formula de SUMIFS para dos condiciones, de Operación y tit
   Dim lRowJ As Long
   Dim lRowAA As Long
   Dim lRowV As Long
   Dim rngCriterio1 As Range
   Dim rngCriterio2 As Range
   Dim rngSuma As Range
'Asignación de los rangos
   lRowJ = Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   lRowAA = Range("AA" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   lRowV = Range("V" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   Set rngCriterio1 = Range("J2" & lRowJ)
   Set rngCriterio2 = Range("AA2" & lRowAA)
   Set rngSuma = Range("V2" & lRowV)
'Uso de los rangos en la fórmula.
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell) = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs _
    (rngSuma, rngCriterio1, "C", rngCriterio2, "=RC[-9]")
'Liberación de los objetos.
  Set rngCriterio1 = Nothing
  Set rngCriterio2 = Nothing
  Set rngSuma = Nothing

' Se autocompleta con la formula
    
    Dim ultimaFila As Long
    ultimaFila = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(ActiveCell.Address & ":L" & ultimaFila)
```

however, the result it throws is zero in each cell that is autocompleted, it does not even put the formula

Comment: You want `formula` if you want to insert a formula. `worksheetfunction` will just calculate.

Comment: Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell).Formula = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs _
    (rngSuma, rngCriterio1, "C", rngCriterio2, "=RC[-10]")
???

Comment: You would literally write the formula you want in the cell. Please see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.formular1c1).

Comment: You're calculating multiple "last row" values from different columns - those may end up having different values if any of those columns are not fully-populated.  Just use *one* "last row" value from a column which will always be fully-populated.

Comment: Also this `Range("J2" & lRowJ)` - if `lRowJ` is (eg) 100 then that gives you `Range("J2100")` which is probably not what you wanted.

Comment: Ok, Thanks! so, I have to rewrite as Range("D10").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(R[-8]C[-1]:R[-1]C[-1],150,R[-8]C:R[-1]C)", but can I use the objects that I created to the Multiple Range Objects method? e.g.  Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS(rngSuma,rngCriterio1,"C",rngCriterio2, "=RC[-9]" )"???

Comment: Yes if you use A1 notation and not R1C1 (so `.Formula` and not `.FomulaR1C1`